# MYSQL order by (whole)number and text

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to order a list with a query :

```
select * from processus order by numero_processus + 0 asc;
```

The problem is I got letters in some. I want the numbers first and then the letters

```
0
J
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
A
FCR 1
FCR 2
PB
M
N
L
L
1.1
1.2
```

How can I do ? Thank you.

Comment: What collation are you using? What version of MySQL are you using? What is the exact datatype of your `numero_processus` column? (And why on earth is a column named "numero" not using a numeric datatype?)

Comment: UTF8 and 5.7.26
This is varchar
I Don't know .. not my database

Comment: Simple `order by numero_processus` must return number firstly - the column has string datatype, and digits ASCII codes are less than letters codes. Exclusion - the values started with minus sign `-`, but I do not see such values.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text

Answer (score 1):

If you want the numbers first, you can use conditional logic.  If by "number" you mean a string that begins with a number:

```
order by ( (numero_processus + 0) = 0 and (numero_processus <> '0') ) desc,
         numero_processus + 0
```

If you want "full" numbers only (rather than just leading digits), then you can use regular expressions.  This should be close enough:

```
order by ( numero_processus regexp '^[-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*$' ) desc,
         numero_processus + 0
```

Comment: Given that both ASCII and Unicode give the `0-9` characters lower ordinal values than `A-Z` and `a-z` then forcing ordinal collation on the column in an `ORDER BY` should be sufficient, no?

Comment: @Dai . . .  (1) There is more than one way to do what the OP wants.  (2) It depends what the OP really wants.